# JQL: Hide `Done` sub-tasks when their parent moved to `Done`

Tags: jira, scrum, jql, scrumboard

Sometimes tasks have lots of sub-tasks, and it is perfectly OK for them being on the board during work on them. With time sub-tasks will be resolved to Done column. And as soon as parent task is also finished and moved to Done - there is no sense to keep and show all its subtasks there.
Please help with JQL filter to hide sub-tasks from `Done` column if/when their parent is moved to `Done`. Basically, it's like collapsing subtasks underneath parent.

I've tried smth like

```
issuetype = Sub-task AND issueFunction in portfolioChildrenOf("Status = Done")
```

but with no success

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
project = PROJECT and type in standardIssueTypes() and status = Done and not (issueFunction in parentsOf("project = PROJECT and type in subtaskIssueTypes() and status = Done"))
```

Note that it will also remove completed issues without subtasks.